# Parent-Child Membership

Tags: civimember, formbuilder

In my organization, parents can register their child for a membership. If a parent registers more than one child for a membership, the parent should be billed for 2 memberships instead of one. The membership role is then given to both parents and the child. I figured I can use inheritance/relationships to set up sharing the membership. But, is there a good way to charge the parents based off how many children (and thereby memberships) they have a relation with? I'm on the latest civicrm using wordpress if that helps.

Comment: I don't know how you can do this in WP if you want each child to have a separate membership, and I don't think Civi FormBuilder will help - but it may be possible if you are not asking for payment at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would probably to create a price set for the membership that asks the parent how many children they are registering and sets that as the quantity.

This wouldn't be foolproof (a parent could fill in the number 1 for the price set and still register 3 children for the price of one), but a small amount of custom code could take care of validation to ensure that doesn't happen.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Would taking payment for multiple memberships work with this method? I know PayPal and omnipay don't support multiple payments on one from. Thank you!

Comment: This method would create only *one* membership (for the parent) with the quantity-of-children determined by the price-set selection. You could then use membership inheritance to propagate memberships to children.

Comment: oh ok that makes a lot more sense. Thank you for the help! I guess the only challenge with that would be if a parent wanted to cancel the membership for one child in the future.

Comment: If you are switching around to having this so the Parent is the 'member' and the children 'inherit' memberships based on a relationship then to cancel membership for one child would just require ending that relationship